# iOS8 AutoLayout issue

Tags: autolayout, ios8

I have AutoLayout issue in iOS8. I used following code to set AutoLayout, its working file when view is load first time , when I tap on back button and again come to the view AutoLayout does not set, both my button and label show at top left position of the screen.

**Here is the Code :**

```
[btnCancel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[lblInfo setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];


 [self setLayoutConstraints:@"V:[btnCancel(==50)]" andHorizontal:@"H:[btnCancel(==100)]" widthConstant:widthConstant heightConstant:heightConstant-80 dictionaty:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(btnCancel) forSubview:btnCancel];

 [self setLayoutConstraints:@"V:[lblInfo(==50)]" andHorizontal:@"H:[lblInfo(==310)]" widthConstant:widthConstant heightConstant:heightConstant-10 dictionaty:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(lblInfo) forSubview:lblInfo];

-(void)setLayoutConstraints:(NSString*)Vformat andHorizontal:(NSString*)Hformat widthConstant:(float)widthConst heightConstant:(float)heightConst dictionaty:(NSDictionary*)NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings forSubview:(UIView*)subview
{
    NSMutableArray *layoutConstraints;
    layoutConstraints = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:Vformat                                                                                                                       options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings]];
    [layoutConstraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:Hformat options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings]];

    NSLayoutConstraint *textFieldCenterConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:widthConst];

    NSLayoutConstraint *textFieldBottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottomMargin relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottomMargin multiplier:1.0 constant:heightConst];
    [self.view addConstraints:layoutConstraints];
    [self.view addConstraints:@[textFieldCenterConstraint,textFieldBottomConstraint]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call your `setLayoutConstraints` at appropriate places e.g. `ViewDidLoad`, `ViewDidAppear`. Also try using `updateConstraintsIfNeeded`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you post this as comment?